# TrueCrypt container sluggish data transfer only in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit, truecrypt

I downloaded two setup files for truecrypt namely `truecrypt-7.1a-linux-x86.tar.gz` & `TrueCrypt Setup 7.1a.exe` one for linux & one for my windows8

I installed both the files in respective OSes & while in Ubuntu I created an `normal AES fat32` encrypted container of 250Gb & utilised truecrypt native GUI to do this. After mounting I started transferring files (of ~2Gb each). To my dismay the speed was extremely sluggish & dropped to 2-3mb/sec while my Core2Duo processor usage surmounted to 98%, the machine overall was a standstill!

After dismounting I repeated mount & transfer files using Linux native [zulucrypt GUI](https://code.google.com/p/zulucrypt/)
but received same sluggish transfer & high CPU usage

While in Win8 on the same machine using native Truecrypt application I mounted & started data transfer but this time I got ~22mb/sec. So how come my Ubuntu isn't providing good speed?